# convert array into proper JSON format for android using PHP

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am using `Codeigniter` to fetch rows. Please go through the below code.

```
//Model

public function selectData() {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_favourites WHERE favourites_status = 1');
    $count = $query->num_rows();

    if($count > 0)
        return $result = $query->result_array();
    else
        return 0;
}

//Controller

$all_favourites = $this->select->selectData();

if(!empty($all_favourites)) {
    foreach($all_favourites as $favourites)
        echo json_encode($favourites);
}
```

From the above code, the output is

```
{"favourite_online_id":"3","favourite_online_url":"ddd","favourite_online_status":"0"}
{"favourite_online_id":"2","favourite_online_url":"http:\/\/www.google.com","favourite_online_status":"0"}
```

But I want the output to be formatted properly to satisfy the android JSON.

The required output is,

```
[
  {
    "favourite_online_id": "3",
    "favourite_online_url": "ddd",
    "favourite_online_status": "0"
  },
  {
    "favourite_online_id": "2",
    "favourite_online_url": "http://www.google.com",
    "favourite_online_status": "0"
  }
]
```

Comment: instead of encoding in `foreach` `encode` the main array. `json_encode($all_favourites)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using

```
if(!empty($all_favourites)) {
    foreach($all_favourites as $favourites)
        echo json_encode($favourites);
}
```

use directly

```
if(!empty($all_favourites)) {

        echo json_encode($all_favourites );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in 2 way

**1st way**

```
if(!empty($all_favourites)) {
  echo json_encode($all_favourites);
}
```

**2nd way**

if you want to add something in that object then

```
$favouriteArray=[];
if(!empty($all_favourites)) {
    foreach($all_favourites as $favourites){
      array_push($favouriteArray, $favourites);
    }
}
echo json_encode($favouriteArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can modify your function

```
public function selectData() {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_favourites WHERE favourites_status = 1');
    $count = $query->num_rows();

    if($count > 0)
        return $result = $query->result_array();
    else
        return array();
}

//Controller

$all_favourites = $this->select->selectData();

// if(!empty($all_favourites)) {
//    foreach($all_favourites as $favourites)
//        echo json_encode($favourites);
// }
echo json_encode($all_favourites);
```